# Парсинг фото друзей ВК C#

Tags: c#, winforms, vkontakte-api

Можно ли сделать парсер через VKAPI на C#(WinForm), который  будет работать для разных аккаунтов? Допустим пользователь запускает парсер, вводит свои данные от ВК и получает фото друзей

Comment: Можно.(доп символы)

Comment: @User12351259599491 Как?